# How to duplicate elements of an array in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I'm trying to duplicate the array elements, for example:

```
var array = ["chicken","nugget","good"];
```

into:

```
var array2 = ["chicken","chicken","nugget","nugget","good","good"];
```

How to done with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idiomatic way would be:

```
["chicken","nugget","good"].flatMap((x) => [x, x]);
```

Be aware not all javascript environments have `flatMap` available yet so transpilation may be required.

Comment: Thanks, this one work perfectly as I wanted!

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
const arr = ["chicken","nugget","good"].reduce(function (res, current, index, array) {
        return res.concat([current, current]);
    }, []);
```

Comment: This creates a lot of intermediate arrays.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to use [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to iterate over the array and insert each item twice into a new array.

```js
var array = ["chicken","nugget","good"];

let array2 = [];

array.forEach(item => {
  array2.push(item, item);
});

console.log(array2);
```

> **NOTE:** If array items are objects, by this method you are duplicating the same
>   reference. In such case, you might want to clone the object before
>   inserting.

Comment: `push` can be called with multiple arguments: `array2.push(item, item)`

Comment: Thanks @slider. Edited the answer.